# Inconsistent output for PHP ReflectionMethod invoke() in PHPUnit

Tags: php, reflection, phpunit

I came across a strange case when using php class reflection in PHPUnit. Following is how I do in straight class, it produces "ChildClass" from get_called_class(), as I expected:

```
class ParentClass {
    static function funcA() {
        echo get_called_class() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

class MyTest {
    public function test() {
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('ChildClass');
        var_dump($reflectionClass);
        $reflectionClass->getMethod('funcA')->invoke(null);
    }
}

$object = new MyTest;
$object->test();
```

It outputs:

```
object(ReflectionClass)#2 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "ChildClass"
}
ChildClass
```

But if I wrap that in a PHPUnit test case, the get_called_class() echo "ParentClass". It definitely changed behavior of invoking method on Reflection class. Did I miss anything in PHPUnit, or PHP ReflectionClass itself?

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testReflection() {
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('ChildClass');
        var_dump($reflectionClass);
        $reflectionClass->getMethod('funcA')->invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Here is the output, notice the last line, it shows "ParentClass"

```
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.class ReflectionClass#221 (1) {
  public $name =>
  string(10) "ChildClass"
}
ParentClass
```

Comment: Is it run under the same php version? How is it possible that `var_dump($reflectionClass);` is different in both of your examples?

Comment: Yes, they are all running under same env on my CentOS VM. Actually var_dump($reflectionClass) gives the same result. But calling invoke() on ReflectionMethod from getMethod() gives different result.

Comment: "Actually var_dump($reflectionClass) gives the same result" --- in your question they are different.

Comment: Ah, my bad. They are indeed different. How could I not see that. They seems like different object. So how 'class' could be dumped instead of 'object'? I tried $reflectionClass->__toString(), it doesn't output like that. And I don't believe we can change PHP core functions.

Comment: I actually haven't seen the `class ReflectionClass#221` output ever

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zerkms to pointing out the obvious diff from the output. I tested it again with different PHP versions. It has described problem with 5.3.3, but not with 5.5.3. That's probably the reason PHPUnit site has this line, "PHPUnit 3.7 requires PHP 5.3.3 (or later), but PHP 5.5.1 (or later) is highly recommended."